# cachingHttpclient cannot ignore header "Cache-Control: no-cache"

Tags: java, caching, cache-control, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache cachingHttpClient to query a REST API from java code.

I want to cache some http response despite receiving "Cache-Control: no-cache" header which cause the cachingHttpClient to not cache the file.

With standalone http proxy such as squid,mod_cache..., I could tweak the configuration to ignore those headers and overide default behaviour.

I'd rather not go for standalone http proxy but rather go for 100% java code.

1. is there another http client that would offer more control on caching ?
2. can I implement an intermediate layer/proxy that would rewrite the headers ?
3. can I patch cachingHttpClient through inheritance ?

Answer (score 2):

The request is being rejected by the `CachedResponseSuitabilityChecker` in the `canCachedResponseBeUsed` method.  If you need different behavior, that's the class to implement your own version of, and then use the long constructor for `cachingHttpClient`

```
CachingHttpClient(HttpClient backend, 
     CacheValidityPolicy validityPolicy,
     ResponseCachingPolicy responseCachingPolicy,
     HttpCache responseCache,
     CachedHttpResponseGenerator responseGenerator,
     CacheableRequestPolicy cacheableRequestPolicy,
     CachedResponseSuitabilityChecker suitabilityChecker, 
     ConditionalRequestBuilder conditionalRequestBuilder, 
     ResponseProtocolCompliance responseCompliance, 
     RequestProtocolCompliance requestCompliance)
```

Comment: The reject point should come from CacheableRequestPolicy. The long constructor could not be inherited by subclass. So, you have to copy the whole source code into your package. This will make bug fix patch difficult.